# React. How to add autoprefixer package in and config it?

Tags: css, reactjs, autoprefixer

I search over the whole internet and do not find an answer on the question - how I can add the vendor prefixes support for my `css` files on production build?

So, I found two articles on this question, but it does not help me `.

1. https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a
2. https://medium.com/@ruanjian/configure-css-for-create-react-app-8681c6eb5f00

Comment: read this [https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader)

Comment: Do you use Webpack? If yes, take a look at [this conf](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/aaf022ca392ad8b485ec35b962ae26640e26aa61/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any vendor prefixes if you have created your React app by the script create-react-app, it does use autoprefixer.